# How to skip relation data at the time of get call

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring and need help.

I have three entity `Exam Category`, `Exam` and `Subject`

In the `Exam Category` entity:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "EXAM_CATEGORY_ID")
private Set<Exam> exams;
```

In `Exam` entity I have defined the relation:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy
@JoinColumn(name = "EXAM_ID")
private Set<Subject> subjects;
```

But when I make a get call for all Exam Category it returns me all data like all exam category with all exams and in exams all subjects.

I don't want subject data in this get call.

But I want subject data when I make a get call for particular any exam.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Hi,   As per the JPA API, OneToMany relationship maintains the objects in lazy loading fashion only. By default the child objects will not loaded. How are you checking whether child objects are loaded or not.? Dont call the getExams method before checking these..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use and excerpt projection that does not include the subject. This excerpt would be used when the collection resource is requested. The single resource would stay the same.

For more information you could consult the documentation:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpts

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this, I think I am not able to explain what I want, can you please go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471797/want-to-include-relationships-in-spring-rest-api,
 here I have explained what I really want.
And really thanks for your reply Mathias.