# Want to include relationships in Spring REST API

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new in Spring.

I have three entity `Invoice, Line and Product`.

(1) If I call `GET /invoices` then I want output like,

```
{
    "invoices": [
        {
            "id": "101",
            "date": "2013-02-14"
        },
        {
            "id": "102",
            "date": "2013-02-18"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have done this, I am able to do this but not able to include relations in the get request.

(2) I want to GET call something like this which include relations.

```
GET /invoices?include=invoice.lines:embed,invoice_line.product:sideload
```

I want output like

```
{
    "invoices": [
        {
            "id": "101",
            "date": "2013-02-14",
            "lines": [
                {
                    "id": "201",
                    "product_id": "301",
                    "amount": 100
                },
                {
                    "id": "201",
                    "product_id": "302",
                    "amount": 100
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "102",
            "date": "2013-02-18",
            "lines": [
                {
                    "id": "203",
                    "product_id": "301",
                    "amount": 100
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "products": [
        {
            "id": "301",
            "name": "Ice Cream"
        },
        {
            "id": "302",
            "name": "Waffles"
        }
    ]
}
```

I got stuck in (2) include relationship, I want to achieve something like this 
need help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best way is to handle this in your controller, with `@RequestParam('include')`  and then do send a response with the correct formatting you want

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by using hibernate annotations.

Your Invoice entity class should look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices") // your table name
public class Invoice implements java.io.Serializable{

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private String date;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "invoices")
    private Set<Line> line = new HashSet<Line>(0);

    // getter and setter method
```

And your Line entity should look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lines")
public class Line implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false) // Invoice id
    private Invoice invoice;

    // product_id and amount and getter and setter method
```

And make sure you have correct relation in your database.
You can take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) for a fully tutorial.

Hope it help and happy coding.

**UPDATE:**

Data Transfer Object for Invoice:

```
public class InvoiceDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private String date;

    // getter and setter methods
}
```

And then create another service that return InvoiceDTO:

```
    Invoice invEntity = em.find(Invoice.class, id);
    InvoiceDTO invDTO = new InvoiceDTO();
    invDTO.setId(invEntity.getId());
    invDTO.setDate(invEntity.Date());

    return invDTO;
```

Then when you need you can return your Invoice within relation or you can return InvoiceDTO object.

Comment: I believe this will cause the relationship to be always converted to JSON, instead of optionally base on the input parameters

Comment: @user3422401 - Every time when I call GET /invoices it always return invoice and lines, I don't want this I want it by URL driven, when I send include lines then only it should return  this.

Comment: @AnshulLonkar You can create another model but not entity that the same with your Invoice that call InvoiceDTO. Then you can create another service that return this InvoiceDTO not Invoice entity within relationship.